# Are bitwise left shifts in JavaScript ES6 (<<) cyclical above a shift of 63?

Tags: javascript, v8, javascriptcore

My understanding of the << bitwise left operator in JS (ES6) is that the void to the right is filled with zeros.

Empirically, however, I notice that in both V8 and JSC, the set bits seem to suddenly reappear if we shift by 64 or more.

```
(255 << 64).toString(2)
//-> "11111111"
```

This is counter to my expectation, which was that larger shifts would indefinitely produce only zeros at right.

I don't immediately see this behaviour defined in the EcmaScript 2016 pages on << – am I missing something, or is the behaviour perhaps undefined for larger shifts ?

Comment: if specifications (as per the answer below) aren't your cup of tea, there's always [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_shift_operators) which states `The right operand should be less than 32, but if not only the low five bits will be used.` - i.e .in your case the low five bits are `00000` ... so, if you left shift 65 instead that's the same as left shift 1

Comment: Shift 32 and you get the same result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The specification ([Section 12.8.3.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-left-shift-operator-runtime-semantics-evaluation)) specifies that the number of bits to shift is masked:

> ShiftExpression : ShiftExpression << AdditiveExpression
>
> 1. Let lref be the result of evaluating ShiftExpression.
> 2. Let lval be
> 3. GetValue(lref).
> 4. ReturnIfAbrupt(lval).
> 5. Let rref be the result of evaluating AdditiveExpression.
> 6. Let rval be GetValue(rref).
> 7. ReturnIfAbrupt(rval).
> 8. Let lnum be ToInt32(lval).
> 9. ReturnIfAbrupt(lnum).
> 10. Let rnum be ToUint32(rval).
> 11. ReturnIfAbrupt(rnum).
> 12. **Let shiftCount be the result of masking out all but the least significant 5 bits of rnum, that is, compute rnum & 0x1F.**
> 13. Return the result of left shifting lnum by shiftCount bits. The result is a signed 32-bit integer.

Since 64 & 0x1F is 0, it means "no shifting" and that is why the bits are "reappearing".

#### tl;dr

The number of bits to shift is capped at 31, i.e.

```
function shiftLeft(number, numShift) {
    return number << (numShift % 32);  // equivalent code
}
```

Comment: specifications are good, but a punish to read - [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_shift_operators) is a little less technical but conveys the same message :p

Comment: Got it – Thank you !  (And I see it in the docs now "The right operand should be less than 32, but if not only the low five bits will be used.")